# Are constraints such as primary key, unique, and foreign key inherited in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, inheritance

Are constraints such as primary key, unique, and foreign key inherited in Oracle through UNDER clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UNDER` keyword is for type inheritance. Types cannot have unique/relational constraints.

> Are constraints such as primary key, unique, and foreign key inherited in Oracle through UNDER clause?

No, because they don't have such constraints so they cannot be inherited.

---

Consider, if you have the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE type1 IS OBJECT (
  type1_value NUMBER(8,0)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE type2 UNDER type1 (
  type2_value NUMBER(8,0)
);
```

And create the object tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1a OF type1 (
  CONSTRAINT table1a__type1_value__pk PRIMARY KEY ( type1_value )
);

CREATE TABLE table1b OF type1 (
  CONSTRAINT table1b__type1_value__pk PRIMARY KEY ( type1_value )
);

CREATE TABLE table2a OF type2;

CREATE TABLE table2b OF type2 (
  CONSTRAINT table2b__type2_value__pk PRIMARY KEY ( type2_value )
);
```

Constraint inheritance doesn't happen but, hypothetically, if they were to inherit constraints which constraint should `table2a` and `table2b` inherit? There is no way the database could determine whether a constraint should be inherited from `table1a` or `table1b` which is why it doesn't happen.

It doesn't make sense to inherit the constraints as the constraints are on the table, and not on the type, and you are inheriting from the type, and not from a table.

To demonstrate that there is no constraint inheritance you can insert some sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1a ( type1_value ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO table1a ( type1_value ) VALUES ( 2 );
INSERT INTO table1a ( type1_value ) VALUES ( 3 );
```

We can insert the same data into `table1b` demonstrating that tables of the same type do not share constraints (otherwise they would also share the same unique index and would not allow duplicate values):

```sql
INSERT INTO table1b ( type1_value ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO table1b ( type1_value ) VALUES ( 2 );
INSERT INTO table1b ( type1_value ) VALUES ( 3 );
```

We can insert the same values into `table2a`, which is a subtype:

```sql
INSERT INTO table2a ( type1_value, type2_value ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO table2a ( type1_value, type2_value ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO table2a ( type1_value, type2_value ) VALUES ( 2, 1 );
```

And we can, again, insert the same values into `table2b`, which is also a subtype and has its own independent primary key:

```sql
INSERT INTO table2b ( type1_value, type2_value ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO table2b ( type1_value, type2_value ) VALUES ( 1, 2 );
INSERT INTO table2b ( type1_value, type2_value ) VALUES ( 2, 3 );
```

There is no constraint inheritance in object tables.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=081db2f3d21dd1dfcd0d86a1d755e2d2)*

---

## Update

From comments:

> but isn't there a reference type? thing like:
>
> ```sql
> create type Person(
>   ID varchar(20) primary key,
>   name varchar(20),
>   address varchar(20)
> ) ref from(ID);
> ```

You appear to be confusing two things as you can't include a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on a type and the syntax is wrong but you can include a `REF` to another object; however, it is not a referential constraint to a particular table but (from the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions127.htm)):

> `REF` takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias) associated with a row of an object table or an object view.

So it is more of a pointer data type than a referential constraint.

For example, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ref_table (
  value REF type1
);
```

Then you can insert data from any/all four of the tables above:

```sql
INSERT INTO ref_table ( value )
  SELECT REF(t) FROM table1a t WHERE type1_value = 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT REF(t) FROM table1b t WHERE type1_value = 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT REF(t) FROM table2a t WHERE type1_value = 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT REF(t) FROM table2b t WHERE type1_value = 2;
```

There is no referential constraint to a particular table; just pointers to objects that are of the type `type1` or a sub-type thereof.

If you want, you could (instead) have added a referential constraint on the `REF` data type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ref_table ADD CONSTRAINT ref_table__value__fk
  FOREIGN KEY ( value ) REFERENCES table1a;
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO ref_table ( value )
  SELECT REF(t) FROM table1a t WHERE type1_value = 1;
```

Would work but inserting references from the other tables would fail.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f0a71cdfbbe11c7a67c96ea148da3a2)*

You can inherit `REF` data types when they are part of an object type but they do not enforce referential integrity as the object they point to could be in any table or column that holds the data type you are pointing to. However, you cannot inherit `FOREIGN KEY` referential constraints as they are applied to a table and have nothing to do with the object types or inheritance.

Comment: but isn't there a reference type? thing like:
create type Person(

ID varchar(20) primary key,

name varchar(20),

address varchar(20))

ref from(ID);

Comment: That syntax is wrong and a `REF` data type is not a constraint; it is a pointer to an object type that could exist in any table.